# Constructor use null value as parameter

Tags: scala, constructor

Following is a simple `scala` class definition, there are 2 constructors defined inside Person class.

**Person.scala:**

```
// class that has field and method,
class Person(var name:String, var age:Short) {
    def this() {
        this("", 0);
    }
    def this(name:String) {
        this(name, 0);
    }
    def hi() = printf("hi, I am %s!\n", name)
}

// var nobody = new Person();
var eric = new Person("Eric", 12);
eric.hi;
```

**The question is**:

- When `age` field is not provided in constructor's argument list, I want to initialize it to null, not 0, what is the proper way to do that. Same requirement for the `name` field.

Comment: Dont use null then, use Option: ```case class Person(name: Option[String]=None, age:Option[Int] = None)``` and then you dont need all those boiler plate constructors

Comment: Firstly, as @maress said, it's not scala way to use null. Secondly, you can't assign `null` to `Short` (`AnyVal`) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the scala class you wanted to create is

```
case class Person(name:String, age:Option[Short] = None) {
    def hi() = println(s"hi, I am $name.\nMy age is ${age.getOrElse("not provided")}.")
}
```

Which returns

```
scala> var eric = new Person("Eric", Some(12));
eric: Person = Person(Eric,Some(12))

scala> eric.hi
hi, I am Eric.
My age is 12.

scala> var eric = new Person("Eric");
eric: Person = Person(Eric,None)

scala> eric.hi
hi, I am Eric.
My age is not provided.
```

Comment: I have one doubt, `this(name, None);` in this expression, what is the `None` means? Is it a value defined somewhere, or it created an object of type `None`?

Comment: Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/2293/options#t=20160812155505693873) from the documentation explaining what `Options` are.